# Create subfolder with same name as parent

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory that needs new sub-folders created in each parent folder with names deriving from the parent folders. 
Example:

current directory:

Directory

- Parent1
- Parent2
- Parent3

future directory:

Directory

- Parent1

  - Parent1_fun
- Parent2

  - Parent2_fun
- Parent3

  - Parent3_fun

The following is my feeble attempt at creating a batch to do this.

```
for /d /r "C:\Desktop\fun" %%i in (C:\Desktop\fun*) do MD %%~i
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to do what you're after:

```
for /f %x in ("%CD%") do md %~nx_fun
```

**Edited** to add: This assumes you're in the parent directory where you want to create the subdirectory.  Hopefully this is enough to point you in the right direction. :-)

**Edit 2**: By 'parent directory', I meant the specific parent directory (e.g., parent1).  To iterate over each of the directories in the *actual* parent (labeled just Directory in your diagram), try something like this:

```
for /d %d in (*) do md %d\%d_fun
```

Given a directory structure like:

```
C:\test
C:\test\dir1
C:\test\dir2
```

...start from `C:\test` and run this.  It will create this structure:

```
C:\test
C:\test\dir1
C:\test\dir1\dir1_fun
C:\test\dir2
C:\test\dir2\dir2_fun
```

Comment: Let me give it a go... and yes, i'm in the parent directory :)

Comment: Well it did more than what I was able to do, but not quite what I'm trying to achieve. That created a folder, with new name, in the directory along with the parent folders... I'm trying to get a folder created inside each parent folder with parent folder name. =) Does that make sense?

Comment: Edited my post to better answer your clarified question.

Comment: Outstanding! That's exactly what I was looking to achieve. Sorry If I wasn't clear to begin with.